# Tag badges "showing top 100 of 201 available badges..." when fewer badges shown

Tags: bug, tag-badges, badge-progress

"Select your next badge" screen shows a message

> showing top 100 of 201 available badges; please use the search box to find a specific badge

when there aren't that many badges shown on the screen (likely because I haven't yet achieved bronze/silver on that many badges yet).

[image: showing top 100 of 201 available badges; please use the search box to find a specific badge]
[image]

Comment: That message doesn't show up for me... at all...

Comment: @TinyGiant -  Shows up for me, but not on my meta profile. Try it on your main profile.

Comment: Yes, it doesn't show up in my meta profile either but it does on my main SO.  Strange considering it's probably similar code that runs both...

Comment: I actually don't see it on my main profile, either. I think it's only appearing because you have a chance at over 100 _bronze_ tag badges. It still shouldn't show up in the silver and gold tabs, of course. (cc @theB)

Comment: I checked on both, couldn't find it anywhere.

Comment: Now I found it. It is on the *tag* badge tracker, not the standard badge tracker.

Comment: Added appropriate tag to reduce confusion :)