# Select your next tag badge to track showing first 100 out of x available tags empty

Tags: bug, tag-badges, badge-progress

In the *select next tag badge to track* popup, if I don't have any silver or gold badges available, I still see a message that says: "Showing first 100 of x available tags" with x being my available bronze badges. I've found another question on Meta asking about this, but without answers: [Tag badges "showing top 100 of 201 available badges..." when fewer badges shown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308697/tag-badges-showing-top-100-of-201-available-badges-when-fewer-badges-shown). I'd like to know if this is a bug or intended behaviour. Here's a screenshot:

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: Since you don't have any bronze tag badges, I'd guess it doesn't think you're eligible for any silver ones?

Comment: Yeah, that's for sure but my question is about whether the text saying that it's showing 100 badges should show up or not in this case.

Comment: Well... it is showing 100 badges, just not on the tab you are on.