# Tag badge tracker - "showing top 100 of x available badges" text is in the wrong position

Tags: bug, tags, design

When opening the tag badge tracker window with all available badges, the text on the bottom is on the top left and looks like it's in the wrong position (it does not have a padding/margin).

It would be much better in a new line and centered.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be the same as this one: [Tag badges "showing top 100 of 201 available badges..." when fewer badges shown](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/308697/tag-badges-showing-top-100-of-201-available-badges-when-fewer-badges-shown)

Comment: @GonçaloPeres龚燿禄This question refers to the incorrect design, the one you linked is about a different issue.